# Display one print dialog box to print multiple files in directory or send all files to printer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, dialog

I'm using `WinForms`. I want to be able to print all TIF images in a particular directory. The problem with my code is that when i try to print all the tif images, the print dialog box opens up for each tif images. For example, If I have 10 tif images in the direcotry, the print dialog box will open up 10 times for each tif image.

**Goal: From these 2 options**

- Have one dialog box like **figure 2** that displays all tif
  images to be printed.
- Send all files in the directory to default printer without the print dialogbox
  poping up.

  ```
  List<string> elements = new List<string>();
  private int ElementCounter;
  private void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\image\Shared_Directory\Printing_Folder\");
      FileInfo[] Files = directory.GetFiles("*.tif"); //Getting Tif files


      foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
      {               

          elements.Add(file.Name);
          string FileToPrint = directory + elements[ElementCounter];

          //Print
          ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(FileToPrint);
          info.Verb = "Print";
          info.CreateNoWindow = true;
          info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
          Process.Start(info);

          ElementCounter++;
      }
  }
  ```

  **Issue**
  [image]

**Figure 2:** This print dialog box contains all the tif images to be printed. *I'm using Windows Explore here to show an example.*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a PrintDocument object along with a PrintPreviewDialog:

```
private PrintDocument printDoc;
private PrintPreviewDialog printPreview;
List<string> elements = new List<string>();
private int ElementCounter;
private int page;

printDoc.BeginPrint += PrintDoc_BeginPrint;
printDoc.PrintPage += PrintDoc_PrintPage;

private void PrintDoc_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    page = 0;
}

private void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(elements[page]), e.MarginBounds);
    page++;
    e.HasMorePages = page < elements.Count;
}

private void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\image\Shared_Directory\Printing_Folder\");
    FileInfo[] Files = directory.GetFiles("*.tif"); //Getting Tif files


    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {              
        elements.Add(file.FullName);
        ElementCounter++;
    }

    printPreview.Document = printDoc;
    printPreview.Show();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, however i get an error in these 2 parts when i pasted the code in `printDoc.BeginPrint += PrintDoc_BeginPrint;`
`printDoc.PrintPage += PrintDoc_PrintPage;` the name printDoc does not exist in the current context.

Comment: one correction it should be `elements.Add(directory+file.Name);` and it worked thank you!

Comment: No problem! You can also use file.FullName which is what I meant to type. I'll correct it in my answer.